# Return json from mvc controller only shows last item in list on page

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the data from a MVC Controller using json, I can get the data and display it in a alert, but when I try to display it on the page, it only shows the last item in the list returned from the controller.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, my code is below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { jsonJewelleryType: ddlJewelleryType },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (request) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = data;
            $.each(items,function (i, item) {
                $.each(item,
                    function (key, value) {
                        $("#catalog-items").html("<div class=\"row\"><h4>" + key + " " + value + "</h4></div>");
                        alert(key + " " + value);
                    });
            });
        }
    });
```

Json Returned

> /------------------------Console Code from Chrome----------------

```
>     1.    {CatalogProducts: Array(1), Pager: {…}, NumberOfRecordsPerPage: 10}
>     1.    CatalogProducts:Array(1)
>     1.    0:
>     1.    CatalogImages:Array(4)
>     1.    0:"image1.jpg"
>     2.    1:"image2.jpg"
>     3.    2:"image3.jpg"
>     4.    3:"image4.jpg"
>     5.    length:4
>     6.    __proto__:Array(0)
>     2.    Description:"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
> dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
> of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
> not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
> typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."
>     3.    DiamondQuality:"Whats This"
>     4.    Image1:null
>     5.    Image2:null
>     6.    Image3:null
>     7.    Image4:null
>     8.    JewelleryType:"Earring"
>     9.    Metal:"9ct Yellow Gold"
>     10.   Price:"299.99"
>     11.   Title:"9ct Yellow Gold Diamond Cluster Stud Earring (1.00ct)"
>     12.   __proto__:Object
>     2.    length:1
>     3.    __proto__:Array(0)
>     2.    NumberOfRecordsPerPage:10
>     3.    Pager:{StartPage: 1, CurrentPage: 1, PageSize: 10, TotalItems: 1, TotalPages: 1, …}
>     4.    __proto__:Object
```

Comment: `$("#catalog-items").html(...)` just overwrites the html each time (you need to `.append()` the items)

Answer (score 2):

By doing `$("#catalog-items").html("<div class=\"row\"><h4>" + key + " " + value + "</h4></div>");` you're resetting the html of the `catalog-items` div each time you pass through.

Try using:

`$("#catalog-items").append("<div class=\"row\"><h4>" + key + " " + value + "</h4></div>");`

Comment: Hi Matt Griffiths thanks that works, but still having problems getting the title description etc. I've tried value[0].title, value.title, value[0] what would be the correct way. Sorry for been novice, but I'm not that great with json

Comment: @PaulThompson Could you post the JSON response please? :)

Comment: @PaulThompson Can you run `success: function (data) { console.log(data); }` and paste the result here for me please - I'm having trouble interpreting your response.

Comment: Hi Matt Griffiths please find console output from Chtome

Comment: @PaulThompson It looks like you could do data.Title, or data[0].title - do any of those work?